# How to parse datetime string with an hour but not a minute in Polars (i.e., "%Y%m%d%H")

Tags: python-polars

In Polars, I have a dataframe with date strings formatted like this

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"date_str": ["d=2023120100", "d=2023120112"]})
```

To parse that into a datetime type, I would do this

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("date_str").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "d=%Y%m%d%H"))
```

But this results in an error

```
ComputeError: Invalid format string: Please either specify both hour and minute, or neither.
```

I'm surprised that Polars requires the datetime string to have both hours and minutes because Pandas doesn't behave this way. Is there some subtle thing I'm missing to parse this datetime with Polars?

Comment: It's due to the underlying rust library used (chrono) https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10178

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been written in the comment, it's due to a limitation in the underlying Rust library Chrono

For now, you could do

```py
In [5]: df.with_columns((pl.col("date_str")+'00').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "d=%Y%m%d%H%M"))
Out[5]:
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ date_str            │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-12-01 00:00:00 │
│ 2023-12-01 12:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Or, if you can use `pyarrow` as a dependency

```py
In [19]: import pyarrow.compute as pc

In [20]: df.with_columns(
    ...:     parsed=pl.Series(pc.strptime(df['date_str'].to_arrow(), 'd=%Y%m%d%H', 'us'))
    ...: )
Out[20]:
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ date_str     ┆ parsed              │
│ ---          ┆ ---                 │
│ str          ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞══════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ d=2023120100 ┆ 2023-12-01 00:00:00 │
│ d=2023120112 ┆ 2023-12-01 12:00:00 │
└──────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```